# Where can I download the Ajax Control Toolkit for ASP.NET version 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Where can I download the Ajax Control Toolkit for ASP.NET 2.0? I can find it for version 3.5 and 4, but they are not working with Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it here:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121

(first ZIP file)